# can someone aid me solving error winmain@16 with simple hello world project

Tags: error-handling

```
#include <iostream>
int Main();
{
    std::cout <<"hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is simple yet i get "undefined reference to 'winmain@1'" i have tried replacing int main with int winmain. But the same problem still occurs.  can use some professional help please. Good vibes please <3

Comment: apologies 'winmain@16' is the full error

Comment: Does it need to be `main` instead of `Main`?

Comment: Hey Robert, it seems as though Case sensitivity isn't the issue here :(

Comment: please remove the semicolon at end of int Main(). I think that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here:

- Not adhering to proper main method name. It should be main() and not Main()
- Misplaced semicolon after int Main(). That terminates the definition and the code that follow is just having a different scope altogether.

If you make these changes, your code should compile successfully.